# Webpack Errors After adding Multiple Entrypoint for Vendor

Tags: reactjs, webpack, config, entry-point

Very new to WP. I have extensively searched for this issue, but they all seem to revolve around making sure the absolute path is correctly resolved, and I'm fairly confident I'm using `path.resolve` correctly as when I have just a single entry point (without vendor) everything works fine.

I am trying to do this on dev server, and am merging different configs. Using just a main single entry works absolutely fine. As soon as I add vendor with its resolved path to my node modules folder.. it errors as shown.

Can you guys tell me what other problems I'm likely to encounter trying to get this (damn) thing production ready for prod deploy?

Based on what you see currently. Anyway thanks in advance.
Folder structure should be visible in the screenshots. It's a pretty standard React folder structure (non-CRA)
 [common](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFNBa.jpg)

Comment: For comparison, when I run build instead of dev server. It only errors once, but with the same error as shown in the screenshot. 
ERROR in vendor
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/mstallings/Projects/React/Beach-Me-FullStack/v3-Beach-Me/node_modules' in '/Users/mstallings/Projects/React/Beach-Me-FullStack/v3-Beach-Me'

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around, but not a concise answer as to why it's done this way (Although this clearly makes the bundle size much smaller.. so maybe that IS the answer.). But declaring explicitly the node modules that I'm using in my project like `const VENDOR_LIBS = { 'react', 'react-dom', 'redux' }` and then passing that variable to the vendor object in the entry array.. Things work.